# Is this a good way of detecting the current active fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm currently trying to determine which fragment is the current active one within the onResume() method.

I'm currently basing the detection off the destination ID. Would the ID be the same for everyone who downloads the app or is it a randomly generated number?

How I'm getting the ID:

```
Navigation.findNavController(getView()).getCurrentDestination().getId()
```

How I'm using it:

```
 if (Navigation.findNavController(getView()).getCurrentDestination().getId() == 2131296382){
                Log.w("Navigation", "The current fragment is the chat fragment");
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do with the information by knowing the current visible fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very bad approach to operate just with numbers - integer ids in your case, called 'magic numbers'.

> Would the ID be the same for everyone who downloads the app

Resource ids will be same on all devices, which have the same version of the app, different versions may have different resource ids, because they are code generated during the build.

If you want to operate with resources ids you need to get them from R.java class  by reference. All resources ids are available in R.java class. In your case R.id.<your_fgagment_id> from your navigation.xml. More about resources ids here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources